# Can BDD NUnit test cases run parallel in selenium Grid?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, nunit, bdd, selenium-grid, selenium-grid2

I have a BDD framework and using NUnit for test execution.I am trying to implement selenium grid wherein as the default configuration ,I have 5 instances of chrome , firefox and 1 of IE. However when i select multiple tests from VS to run from a node on lets say chrome, they only run sequentially and not in parallel.
I tried using MaxInstances and MaxSessions also.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Grid has got nothing to do with scheduling tests in sequence or in parallel. You would need to configure NUnit to run tests in parallel. The Grid is merely an execution environment which by default will support parallel test execution, but since the tests need to be spun off in parallel, which NUnit should be doing.

Comment: okay thanks .Just a doubt , I am doing the same (NUnit) with saucelabs(execution env) and it is executing in parallel out there.Trying to figure out that since I haven't configured NUnit to run parallel.

Comment: You would need to share some code in that case, which you run against both SauceLabs and also against a Selenium Grid. Also share the command you are using to spin off a Selenium Hub and a node.